# Insert an object to neo4j via javascript API

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

How can I insert an entire object into Neo4J using JS API? (without providing each and every property)

I've tried the following.([link](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters-create-node-with-properties))

```
session.run('UNWIND $obj as obj2 \n CREATE (p:Animals) \n set p=obj2 \n RETURN p', { obj: results.value })
```

where 
`results.value = {id:"abc", name:"xyz", createdOn: new Date()}`

But it gives the following error

> Neo4jError: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Please, post the content of `results.value`.

Comment: updated with the content.

Comment: Since `results.value` is not a list, I think you should not use `UNWIND`. So change your query to `CREATE (p:Animals) set p=$obj RETURN p` and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j database supports properties of types ([docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/values/)):

- Integer
- Float
- String
- Boolean
- List of these types

Probably the object stored in `results.value` has a property containing a complex object, something like:

```
{
    prop1 : 1
    complexProp : {
        propX : "abc",
        propY : 1,
    }
}
```

In the case of the above structure, the `complexProp` property will be the cause of your error because its type not fits in any Neo4j supported types.

So I think you have two alternatives.

1 - Move all sub-properties to the root, like:

```
 {
     prop1 : 1
     propX : "abc",
     propY : 1
 }
```

2 - Create a different node type for `complexType` property and use a relation between the two nodes.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I have some (new Date()) values. without them object inserted successfully. with dates they give the error. Thanks for the help.